# Using msgraph-sdk python package how to get the children of a drive's root?

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api

Using 1.0.0a9 I was able to use this line to get the children of the root of a drive:

`children = await (self.app_client.drives_by_id(drive.id).root.children.get())`

but after upgrading to 1.0.0a11 I get "'RootRequestBuilder' object has no attribute 'children'"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this the interface changed so I had to change the code to the following (as of v1.0.0a12):

```
children = await self.app_client.drives.by_drive_id(drive.id).items.by_drive_item_id('root').children.get()
```